# Why are allocators to containers passed as template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, allocator

Particularly, why do we have

```
template<typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
class vector
{
    A alloc;
    //...
};
```

instead of

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    allocator<T> alloc;
    //...
};
```

I saw this in a C++ manual and it confused me quite a bit. What other kinds of allocators could one possibly want/need?

Comment: and how are you going to specify the allocator?

Comment: One could want an allocator that uses a static memory block instead of the heap. After the vector is gone one can then deallocate the whole block at once instead of individual pieces, reducing the amount of book-keeping and improving efficiency. The first version allows writing such a custom allocator while the second doesn't.

Comment: If there was only one allocator (the free store), then there wouldn't be any need for `allocator<T>` at all. The system would just go straight to the free store. So your question should have been "Why do we have allocators at all? Why not just hard-code `new` and `delete`?

Comment: @Raxvan: 17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std] 1  "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy indeed, my information was wrong, can anyone delete the comment so it does not misinform people ?

Comment: @Raxvan:  It looks like you managed to correct it, so it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this would work with only one allocator - standard one. But what if you want to allocate memory differently? For example, you might want to use shared memory, or file-backed memory, or anything else.

This is the whole point of having allocators - to allow user to customize the way memory is going to be allocated and freed.

Comment: This makes sense. I never considered any other way to allocate memory other than to grab a chunk out of the free store when it's requested. Thank you!

Comment: @AldenBernitt, shared memory is a first thing which comes to mind. Than you have your static allocators (which do not really allocate from dynamic memory) or, for example, thread-optimized allocators.

Comment: Another useful allocator is a debugging/instrumenting allocator.

Comment: @RaymondChen although in general, one tends to want that globally rather than on a per-container basis - so it ends up being a compiler flag to turn std::allocator into a debugging one.

Comment: Hmm.  "Instrumented" - yes, I can actually see that being more useful on a per-container basis.