# Why Inherriting Std:Allocator is a Bad idea?

Tags: c++, allocator

I went through multiple questions on StackOverflow, to understand why extending the std::allocator is a bad idea. For instance:-

[Why not to inherit from std::allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796/why-not-to-inherit-from-stdallocator) mentions that std::allocator doesn't provide a virtual destructor but what exactly is the impact of this?

Also [Why are allocators to containers passed as template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325069/why-are-allocators-to-containers-passed-as-template-parameters) mentions that until the class takes a template it won't let the class take different types of allocators.

Is it not possible to extend and modify the behavior of std::allocator to allocate memory from shared memory, or file-backed memory? **What parts of std::allocator can't be modified even after extending the class and why not?**

There are certain design decisions we need to make before we proceed further, so wanted to understand the reason why people prefer their own allocators instead of extending and modifying the behavior of default allocator.

Comment: There isn't much of a point to doing that. You are going to replace `.allocate` and `.deallocate` anyway and you don't have to do much more to write your own allocator class anyway.

Comment: The top answer in the first linked question basically answers your question, doesn't it? (With C++20 even the custom allocator class shown in that answer can be further simplified.)

Comment: The answer suggests, there's little reason to implement std::allocator due to the existence of std::allocator_traits inside stl, but it doesn't suggest why it's a bad idea or if it's not a bad idea. Also, I don't think in a production scenario one would rely on a minimal allocator.

Comment: As the answer explains, there is no particular reason that inheriting from `std::allocator` would be bad if the allocator is used only according to the allocator requirements (that means not polymorphically, so that the missing virtual destructor is irrelevant). But as it also explains there is no point to complicating the custom allocator that way, since inheriting and overwriting member functions from `std::allocator` is pretty much exactly as much work as implementing an allocator from scratch. `std::allocator` itself pretty much is as simple as shown in that answer (since C++20).

Comment: The flip side is "Inheriting from std::allocator, what's the point?"  Since `std::allocator` was not designed to be inherited from (it does not have a virtual destructor, nor any virtual functions as extension points for derived classes), and cannot be used *polymorphically*, and any functions it provides will have bindings to its own functions so would need to be shadowed (rewritten) in the derived class.